# Convert byte[] to Vector

Tags: java, android, sqlite, vector, byte

I stored a Vector<'String> into a BLOB field in a sqlite DB.
The problem is when I want to get that Vector, it has to be with cur.getBlob (method from a Cursor cur) and it returns a byte[], the question is, how can I get my vector from these byte[].
Thanks!!!

Comment: What's the problem with `v = new Vector<Byte>(); for(byte b : cur.getBlob()) v.add(b);`?

Comment: Ops, i forgot to say that my data y that Vector are Strings... Vector<String>

Comment: Are you saying that your data is "serialized" into the field?

Comment: Exactly... and i don't find out the way to get its original format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have any experience with android but from java viewpoint this should work:

```
byte[] youByteArray;

ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(youByteArray);
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
// Will throw compiler warnings but should work fine.
Vector<String> yourVector = (Vector<String>) is.readObject();
```

References: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:1285601748584

Comment: @mesacuadrada Accept the answer if it worked :) I too should be pushing myself to learn some android.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector<byte[]> records = new Vector<byte[]>();
records.add(byteData);
```

Comment: thanks, but it's a Vector<String> returned as byte[] so i need to convert that byte[] to Vector<String>...